# Have java find/read a file from user input?

Tags: java, file, input

The program must print the text in file I ask it to read.
The problem is I coded it to read the text from a specific file

```
 File file = new File("numbersonnumbers.txt");
 Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
```

How do I get the program to read the text from a file specified by user input?
*The file is going to be in the same directory/folder as the program so that's not an issue.

EDIT: My prior attempt at user input

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
File file = new File(filename);
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: The code you just edited in isn't relevant in the slightest assuming it works in the case of the hard-coded `"numbersonnumbers.txt"` file fine.  And if it doesn't work on that file, then I'd delete this question and focus on fixing that issue before addressing letting the user type a file name in.

Comment: @nhgrif
it does work...the whole while loop set up is the point of the program...

Comment: Then that code is irrelevant.  You need to include the relevant code.  Specifically, the code where you've attempted taking user input for a file name and sending that to your `File file = new File(someFile);` line.  And the error message you're getting, if you're getting one.

Comment: those are the only two parts of the code.....

Comment: i posted my attempt...literally...did not work

Comment: What did you type in?  And what happened?  `"did not work"` isn't very helpful considering you want volunteers to debug your program.

Comment: 'code' javac Lab02.java
java Lab02 'code'

then pressing enter resulted in

"error running program"

Comment: then when I tried typing the file name next to it 
java Lab02 file.txt

it went goes into limbo

Comment: Can you just try typing `"numbersonnumber.txt"` as the file name since you know your code already works for this file?  And then clearly explain the actual result.  `"goes into limbo"` is not an acceptable description of what's happening by any measure.

Comment: that doesnt work either!  for whatever reason..unless i specify within the code the file i want it to read..it doesn't take

Comment: I don't know what to tell you.  "doesn't work", "doesn't take" and "goes into limbo" are completely unacceptable descriptions of what's actually happening.  If you can't be more specific with your errors, no one can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a `String` variable, such as `someUserFile`, take user input.  Then...

```
File file = new File(someUserFile);
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
```

You may want to check their input and append `".txt"` to the end of their input.

If this works:

```
File file = new File("numbersonnumbers.txt");
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
```

Then this:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
File file = new File(filename);
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
```

Will do the exact same thing assuming you type `numbersonnumbers.txt` and type that exactly.

Assuming you type `numbersonnumbers.txt` exactly, the second snippet does the EXACT same thing as the first snippet.

Comment: I tried that and the compiler accepted that...then the program went into limbo.

Comment: ALSO if i press enter after words it says it can't find the file

Comment: @WeekzGod: I think you'll have to show a bit more of the program if anyone is going to be able to help much further.

Comment: @WeekzGod You'll need to show us what you've tried.  Including explicitly telling us what you input and what the file is named.

Comment: @nhgrif the help suppleid below is literally what i tried before...nearly word for word.

Comment: @WeekzGod `"nearly word for word"` Then include it in your question.  Your question should include all relevant code to what you've attempted.  If you're getting error messages, your question should include those.  I can't GUESS at what your error is, and I'm not going to write your program for you.

Comment: @nhgrif
    String filename = args[0];
     File file = new File(filename);
     Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

figured it out

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should ask the user the input the filename. Then just replace the "numbersonnumbers.txt" in your code to the variable that you set for the user input.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What is the filename?");
String input = in.nextLine();
File file = new File(input);
```

Comment: I DID EXACTLY THIS!!! and the compiler accepted that...then the program went into limbo.

Comment: ALSO if i press enter after words it says it can't find the file

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String fileName = input.nextLine();
File file = new File(fileName);
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: I DID EXACTLY THIS!!!
 and the compiler accepted that...then the program went into limbo.

Comment: ALSO if i press enter after words it says it can't find the file

Answer (score 0):

**1)** The program must print the text in file:

- Lets call this file, **dataFile.text**, or **dataFile.dat** (either way works)
- Assuming that the client will be inputing any file, we must get the file's name...

  **These Java statements will do the trick:**

  *// Create a Scanner to read user's file name*
- ***Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);***

  *// Request the file name from client*
- ***System.out.println("Enter name of input file: ");***

  *// Gets client's file name*
- ***String fileName = scanFile.nextLine();***

  *// scanFile, scans the new File fileName (client's file), which is located in the src directory. The "src/" represents the path to the file (client's file).*
- **Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File("src/" + fileName));**

  - Since the problem states the file, "will be located in the same directory as the program," its not an issue.

***---------------------------------------------------------------------------------***

**2)** The problem is I coded it to read the text from a specific file

- Yes, all you did was create file of your own called, "numbersonnumbers.txt," this is exactly the code you should be following in the solution to this problem, but instead of typing "numbersonnumbers.text", you will be using the client's input file, which is the String variable "fileName" in the previous code...*

  File file = new File("numbersonnumbers.txt");

  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

**Corrected: File file = new File("src/" + fileName);**

Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file); // Will scan all the file's data

**Corrected More: Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("src/" + fileName));**

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**3)** The program must print the text in file

- Now to print the data items in the file to the console you simply, copy every item in the file, to an array, list, or tree depending on specifications of implementation, but this is obviously begininer programming so, never mind lists and trees, use an array.

So you have completed upto either Scanner scanFile in #1 or Scanner inputFile in #2

Now, create an array, obviously the type of array would be based on the type of data items in the file... Strings for (e.g., month names) or int for (e.g., ID numbers .. ect)

Assuming the data items in the file are names of months (jan, feb, march) we will make an array of type String.

**String[] fileData = new String[100];** // has random length (100)

// Now we will be copying every item from the file into the array, you will need place holder value to keep track of the position during the traversal (stopping at every item) of the file's items.

**int i = 0;** // itialize the start of the traversal (index 0 of the file items)

**while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {** // While file has input on next line, read from file.

```
    fileData[++i] = scanFile.nextLine(); // Input file data and increment i

    System.out.println(fileData[i]); // Prints all of the file's data items

    } // end while
```

Respectfully,
-!di0m

Answer (score 0):

You got almost everything you need in your code already. You just need to re-arrange your lines of code properly, and add couple more.

you need two steps: scan what the user enters as full file path, then scan the actual file data as follows:

```
// Scanner Object to be used for the user file path input
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

// Asks the user to enter the full path of their file
System.out.print("Enter your full file path: ");

// Stores the user input file path as a string
String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

// Creates a File object for the file path, and scans it
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File(filename);
```

Now you can read the scanned File `inputFile`. For example you can use a `while` loop to read one line at a time to read all data and print it out as follows:

```
// Reads one line at a time, and prints it out
while(inputFile.hasNext) {
    System.out.println(inputFile.nextLine());
```

Or you can put each line's raw data (trimmed and split) in an array and print out each line as an array as follows:

```
// Declares a String array[] to be used for each line
String[] rawData;    

// Reads one line at a time, trims and split the raw data,
// and fills up the array with raw data elements, then prints 
// out the array. it repeats the same thing for each line.
while (scanner2.hasNext()) {
    rawData = scanner2.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rawData));
}
```